# react-aria-components Menu hides the outer scrollbar when the content is opened

Tags: reactjs, scroll, menu, react-aria

I'm integrating the `react-aria-components` library into my codebase and trying to create a few dropdown items for the user. I'm running into an issue though where the scrollbar containing the dropdown buttons on the page will disappear. The dropdown menu in the [documentation](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/Menu.html) follows a similar pattern

I can use `isNonModal=true` to hide it but the docs mentions this isn't recommended and has also caused some other issues (dropdowns not closing correctly). Wondering if anyone has run into this/if there's a common solution that I'm missing here, or maybe Menu isn't the correct component to use here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.